# Get binary content of char variable in C as it is

Tags: c, character-encoding, char

Is there a way to print binary content of char variable as it is. Means not to convert the variable in to ASCII.

For example,

```
char c =  1000001;
printf("%c\n", c);
```

This print

`A`

But I want to display without convert it to ascii something like below one.

```
1000001
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: so you want  print out the binary representation of a char right?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by as follows

A char in C is guaranteed to be 1 byte, so loop to 8.
Within each iteration, mask off the highest order bit.
Once you have it, just print it to standard output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
      char c =  1000001;
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          printf("%d", !!((c << i) & 0x80));
      }
      printf("\n");

      return 0;


 }
```

or you can also use `itoa` library function as follows

```
char c = 'C'
char output[9];
itoa(c, output, 2);
printf("%s\n", output);
```

One more solution also

```
char c = 'C';
int i = 0;
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        putchar( (c & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0' );
    }
    putchar('\n');
```

Comment: c = 1000001; is not a char. the correct is c = 0b1000001;

Answer (score 1):

can try looping.

scan your character,say 'A'.
Get its ASCII(65).
Divide 65 by 2 till quotient is zero, store remainder in array/dynmalloc .
read the array reverse

65/2 32 ***1***
32/2 16 ***0***
16/2 8  ***0***
8/2 4 ***0***
4/2 2 ***0*** 
2/2 1 ***0***
1/2 0 ***1***